# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'cart' of '(0 , react_redux__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.useSelector)(...)' as it is undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit, redux-persist

I am getting above error while using useSelecor() to get state value from redux.
Got this error while i applied react-persist.

error line :- const { cart  } = useSelector(state => state.cart);

Here is the code for store.js

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
     import CartSlice from "./CartSlice";
     import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
     import { persistReducer, persistStore } from "redux-persist";

     const persistConfig = {
         key: 'root',
         storage,
     };

     const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, CartSlice);

     const store = configureStore({
         reducer: {
             cart: persistedReducer,
         }
     })

     export default persistStore(store);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you didn't set up the RTK with `redux-persist` correctly. The error message means the `state.cart` is `undefined` and can't destructure property `cart` of `undefined`.

The second parameter of [`persistReducer`](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist#persistreducerconfig-reducer) function is a ***reducer*** function, but you passed a state slice which returned by `createSlice()` API I guess.

The below example will persist `cart` state in local storage:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';

import { configureStore, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
import { persistReducer, persistStore, PURGE, REGISTER, REHYDRATE, FLUSH, PAUSE, PERSIST } from 'redux-persist';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';

const cartSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'cart',
    initialState: {
        cart: {
            items: [1, 2, 3],
        },
    },
    reducers: {},
});

const cartPersistConfig = {
    key: 'cart',
    storage,
};

const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        cart: persistReducer(cartPersistConfig, cartSlice.reducer),
    },
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
        getDefaultMiddleware({
            serializableCheck: {
                ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
            },
        }),
});

const persistor = persistStore(store);

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root')!;
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate loading={<p>loading state...</p>} persistor={persistor}>
            <App />
        </PersistGate>
    </Provider>,
);
```

```
localStorage.getItem('persist:cart') 
// {"cart":"{\"items\":[1,2,3]}","_persist":"{\"version\":-1,\"rehydrated\":true}"}
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-76660831-tgzwt9?file=/src/index.tsx)

Further reading: [Use with Redux-Persist](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#use-with-redux-persist)